# Factors that affect dynamic memory allocation

Tags: memory, operating-system, kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to know what are all the factors that affect malloc behavior (or other allocation functions).

Things I know:

1. The vm.overcommit_memory variable.
2. Setting limits for malloc size.
3. 32/64 bit platform.

Thing I assume matter:

1. Different kernel versions?
2. How the OS handles swapping?
   And the OS itself?

Please correct me if I am wrong and if you know something else please comment down below.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i just want a list of things that affect malloc() behavior

Comment: by behavior i mean returned pointer or in some cases NULLPTR

Answer (score 0):

The swapfile size, found in / affects allocation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).